# Is my logic true?

Tags: complex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$\sup\space{|a_1(z_1-z_2)+a_2(z_1^2-z_2^2)+\space...|}\space\ge\space \sup\space{|a_1(z_1-z_2)|}$

If it is, then how can I prove it?

Here $z_1,z_2\space\in\space\mathbb C\space$ such that $|z_1|,|z_2|\le1$

Comment: What's $. . . $ ?

Comment: continues to countably infinite terms.

Comment: You are taking two arbitrary points in the unit disk and asking if $\sup|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|\geq\sup|f'(0)(z_1-z_2)|$ for arbitrary holomorphic function there. If not for two separate $\sup$s it would be equivalent to $|f'(0)|\leq\sup\left|\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}\right|$, which is true. As it is, it is false.

Comment: Yes, is it true?

Comment: What's a_i?.........

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_1=1000, a_2=-1,$ all others $0$.  The right is $2000,$ achieved when $z_1,z_2$ are opposite on the unit circle.  In those cases the left will be $1998$